# Contextual Filters using Taxonomy Works in Preview but not on Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I've been working on this issue for a few weeks now and I can't seem to get it to a point where it's reliable and complete.

I'm trying to use a view to display a bunch of results based on a taxonomy I've created. Therefore, on page example.com/music, it'll display all articles labeled "music". I've followed the instructions on this post exactly: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/9339. It works! Well, when I do the preview at the bottom of my window, it works. On the actual site, it doesn't display it properly.

What could be happening?

Here's what my preview looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u6h4gux6mubk97/vp1.PNG?dl=0
As you can see, it's displaying two articles. Since there are only two articles with the taxonomy term "viewpoints", this makes sense.

Here's what my page looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbjho76oy517ky6/vp2.PNG?dl=0
The "viewpoints" articles are present, but so are all the others. It didn't filter.

These are my settings, if that helps:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtkebv4c52imsna/vp3.PNG?dl=0
"Block" and "Page" have the same settings.

Any advice would be MUCH appreciated!

My actual site is http://ccdrupal.dor.org/viewpoints.

Thanks!
Brendan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing on the taxonomy ID rather than the taxonomy name on the front end?

Also could you show me the settings of the contextual filter?